# CSS Grid Arrangement?

Tags: css, grid

Is there a better way of doing this grid using CSS?

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.grid {
overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
width: 25%;
color: #FFF;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.box .content {
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ahoSeBIW/8/edit)

Also is it possible to make it fit within the window's height as well as the width? ...and remove these annoying pixel width gaps that occur as particular dimensions:

[image]

Comment: to draw square ... you got it right , to draw the grid all hover the window, you ned much more boxes ... if this is only one img, then background-repeat is fine
  html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
  background-size: 25%;
}

Comment: The image is there as a placeholder anything in a context div should be made square by the grid.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to fill the body with squares, that is a good way to do it.

If you want to fill all the height also, there are several posibilities; it's unclear what is exactly what you want. But since it seems that you want squares, the only approaches left are

1. Create more divs
2. Make the width of your squares higher than 25%

The pixel gaps happen because there are pixel roundings in the size calculus. The best way to solve that is to change background-size to cover (instead of contain)

Comment: Thanks the pixel issue is solved the other one was to make the grid fit both width and height by scaling the `.box`. The grid fits the window width but not the height as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/MuPAVqj.png) (notice the scroll bar).

Comment: Yes, I agree that it doesn't fit, but how do you plan to make it fit ? because you can't make a grid composed of 4x4 squares to a non-square window. Or is it enough to clip it and just show part of the squares ? I that case it's just a overflow: hidden ..

Comment: No clipping it should just resize the grid by which ever one is smallest.